# IOS App Build issue: Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I am trying to build my IOS app (developed using capacitor and ionic frameworks).
Just after integrating Google Firebase and adding Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist file I am having followng error while building my app in XCode.

**Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code**

```
CodeSign /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    cd /Users/piyush/Downloads/ncsmobileapp/ios/App
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    
    Signing Identity:     "-"
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/App.app.xcent --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app

/Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried cleaning the build cahce, restarting the xcode.
re-building the app through capacitor, but nothig solved this issue yet.
Can anyone help in solving this issue?

**Update**

While archiving the app following error occurs:

```
CodeSign /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    cd /Users/piyush/Downloads/ncsmobileapp/ios/App
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    
    Signing Identity:     "Apple Development: Piyush Aggarwal (ZWHGYV6A62)"
    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: app.neo.school"
                          (d2353688-03d7-47ff-942f-4f34fd4c6a93)
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 5FE6CDFE4B615D56B70C5DAEB7A151005A1122AE --entitlements /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/App.app.xcent --generate-entitlement-der /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app

/Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Your Signing Identity says `"-"`, which doesn't seem like a valid signing identity. Have you tried figuring out how signing should be setup?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes, I have created 1 key in In Apple developer accont and registered is in google firebase accoumt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to resources folder.
I created that folder to add my GoogleServices-Info.plist file.

I renamed my resources folder and changaed the path to my GoogleServices-Info.pllist file by following code in build phrases of the app in xcode:

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/App/[FOLDER NAME]"

        cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;
```

[image]

Comment: I fking hate stupid Apple. This problem wasted me a lot of time. After seeing your answer I just renamed the "Resources" folder to a random name and it worked. You know what? That folder was named "Resources" because I was following their official tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to delete the derived data and clean the build.

Steps to delete derived data:-

1.Open your project,Go to files -> Workspace Settings

Then you will find a derived data location with an arrow:-

Just click on that arrow,after that you will find a folder named derived data,
delete all the files inside derived data folder.
Then it will working fine.
[image: Check Screenshot Of derived data location here]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same (random) issue when Archiving project where OneSignal (specifically `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`) framework is included. What I have to do to make it work (w00t) is to change `KeyChain` `Trust` setting on `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority` (Expires: Tuesday, 7 February 2023 at 22:48:47 Central European ) certificate back to `Use System Defaults` and then again back to `Always Trust`. I have no idea why this works, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder in the project with a name “Resources”. I had to rename it, and then I could compile the project.